# Ruby/Rails working with gsub and arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gsub

I have a string that I am trying to work with in using the gsub method in Ruby. The problem is that I have a dynamic array of strings that I need to iterate through to search the original text for and replace with.

For example if I have the following original string (This is some sample text that I am working with and will hopefully get it all working) and have an array of items I want to search through and replace.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
a = ['This is some sample text',
     'This is some sample text',
     'This is some sample text']
```

so a is the example array, and then loop through the array and replace the value

```
a.each do |s|
    s.gsub!('This is some sample text', 'replacement')
end
```

Answer (score 21):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > arr = ["This is some sample text", "text file"]  
 => ["This is some sample text", "text file"] 

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > arr = arr.map {|s| s.gsub(/text/, 'document')}
 => ["This is some sample document", "document file"]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Replace everything

Using [Array#fill](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-fill).

```rb
irb(main):008:0> a
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>nil, :e=>5}
irb(main):009:0> a.values
=> [1, 2, 3, nil, 5]
irb(main):010:0> a.values.fill(:x)
=> [:x, :x, :x, :x, :x]
```

### Replace only matching elements

Using [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and a [ternary operator](https://www.w3resource.com/ruby/ruby-ternary-operator.php).

```rb
irb(main):008:0> a
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>nil, :e=>5}
irb(main):009:0> a.values
=> [1, 2, 3, nil, 5]
irb(main):012:0> a.values.map { |x| x.nil? ? 'void' : x }
=> [1, 2, 3, "void", 5]
irb(main):016:0> a.values.map { |x| /\d/.match?(x.to_s) ? 'digit' : x }
=> ["digit", "digit", "digit", nil, "digit"]
```