# Replace strings from one array with strings in another in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, replace

Similar to [Ruby/Rails working with gsub and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066349/ruby-rails-working-with-gsub-and-arrays).

- I have two arrays, "errors" and "human_readable".
- I would like to read through a file named "logins.log"  replace
  error[x] with human_readable[x]
- I don't care where the output goes, stdout is fine.

  ```
  errors = ["0xC0000064", "0xC000006A", "0xC0000071", "0xC0000072", "0xC0000234"]
  human_readable =  ["Unknown User", "Bad Password", "Expired Password", "Account Disabled", "Account Locked"] 
  file = ["logins.log"]

  file= File.read()
  errors.each
  ```

  lost...

I am sorry, I know this is a dumb question and I am trying but I am getting tangled up in the iteration.

What worked for me (I am sure the other answer is valid but this was easier for me to understand)

```
 #Create the arrays
 errors = ["0xC0000064", "0xC000006A", "0xC0000071", "0xC0000072", "0xC0000234"]
 human_readable =  ["Unknown User", "Bad Password", "Expired Password", "Account Disabled",  "Account Locked"]
```

#Create hash from arrays
 zipped_hash = Hash[errors.zip(human_readable)]

#Open file and relace the errors with their counterparts
 new_file_content = File.read("login.log").gsub(Regexp.new(errors.join("|")), zipped_hash)

#Dump output to stdout
 puts new_file_content

This is awesome and will become the template for a lot of stuff, thanks a million.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
errors = ["0xC0000064", "0xC000006A", "0xC0000071", "0xC0000072", "0xC0000234"]
human_readable =  ["Unknown User", "Bad Password", "Expired Password", "Account Disabled", "Account Locked"]

zipped_hash = Hash[errors.zip(human_readable)]
#=> {"0xC0000064"=>"Unknown User", "0xC000006A"=>"Bad Password", "0xC0000071"=>"Expired Password", "0xC0000072"=>"Account Disabled", "0xC0000234"=>"Account Locked"}

new_file_content = File.read("logins.log").gsub(/\w/) do |word|
  errors.include?(word) ? zipped_hash[word] : word
end

or

new_file_content = File.read("logins.log").gsub(Regexp.new(errors.join("|")), zipped_hash)

puts new_file_content
```

Comment: Thank you. Putting the solution above for posterity (assuming I got am not missing something).

Comment: +1 - you may want to use `Regexp#union` instead of `String#join` as it will escape special characters for you - `Regexp.union(%w(^ foo.bar)) #=> /\^|foo\.bar/`